# Django save child from parent

Tags: django

I have this code, thats works fine:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Model1s"
        ordering = ('sioticket',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model1, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    cpm = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Model2s"
        ordering = ('sioticket',)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        vartype = self.name.type
        self.cpm = vartype
        return super(Model2, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I need to ejecute save() of Model2 from save() of Model 1. Or, from save() of Model1, do:

```
vartype = self.name.type
self.cpm = tipo
```

But the problem is that, in parents I don't know if is it possible to access to save() of its childs classes or how to change values of its childs classes from save's parents.

Also I have to say, that, if I create a new Model1 and Model2 works fine, but if I update type from Model1, it don't replicate to "cmp" of Model2.

I've tried this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Model1s"
        ordering = ('sioticket',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model1, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        children = self.objects.all()
        for child in children:
            if child._meta.verbose_name_plural=="Model2s":
                child.save()

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    cpm = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Model2s"
        ordering = ('sioticket',)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tipo = self.name.type
        self.cpm = tipo
        return super(Model2, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Notice that:

```
children = self.objects.all()
for child in children:
   if child._meta.verbose_name_plural=="Model2s":
        child.save()
```

But I have the next error:

```
Manager isn't accessible via Model1 instances
```

I'm newer in Django and I would appreciate help.

Comment: Maybe if you could include a "why you're trying to do this", someone might be able to suggest a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I've founded a solution on my own.

The solution was:

```
for obj in Model1.objects.all():
   for i in obj.model2_set.all():
       i.save()
```

Thank you all!